Decomposition of $R[G]$ ring, from decomposition of $k[G]$
I was reading a paper on "Abelian extension of regular local ring". I have attached the paper Here
there I found the following statement,
$R$ is regular local ring,

Let $k$ be the residue field of $R$. Since the order of $G$ is relatively prime to the characteristic of $k, G$ is Abelian, and $k$ is algebraically closed, $k[G]$ is isomorphic as a ring to a product of copies of $k$. Since $R$ is complete, this decomposition can be lifted to $R[G]$, and $R[G]$ is isomorphic as a ring to a product of copies of $R$. Write this decomposition:
$$
R[G] \cong R_1 \times \ldots \times R_n ; \quad \text { each } R_i \text { isomorphic to } R
$$

I get the decomposition of $k[G]$, but can't manage to get how that decomposition is lifted to $R[G]$.
It is like Henselian ring, but can not proof. If you have some reference then please help.
